# What does "ctrl+shift+a>m" keyboard shortcut acually mean?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I was reading the [documentation](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf/#shortcut-kitty.Increase-background-opacity) for the **kitty** terminal emulator. It has a keyboard shortcut defined as `ctrl+shift+a>m`. I understand the `ctrl+shift+a` part, but what does the `>m` mean?

Comment: Tried pressing Ctrl, Shift and `a` together, followed by pressing `m` separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indicates a [multi-key shortcut](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf/#keyboard-shortcuts): several keystrokes, separated by `>`. So `ctrl+shift+a>m` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, followed by <kbd>m</kbd> (without modifiers).